Swedish Migration Resident Card Appeal
My resident card for Spouse of EU citizen (Danish) in Sweden was rejected in July as my wives savings was not enough for 5 years of self sufficiency, as she did not have a job at the time. We appealed in August and my wife began workin. Today I received word from our lawyer that the court is ready to make a decision on our case and that they need her payslips to prove she is working and that she makes enough to support us.
My question is: Can the migration card deny my appeal on the basis that my wife falls just short of the amount provided to us by migration? (22,000 SEK) I am under the impression that as long as she is working - she retains her right of residence in Sweden. Can someone please clarify?
